# Shrink and change background navbar on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to make my navbar shrink and change background color as soon as I scroll. I attempted some of the javascript solutions provided in a similar question but it did not seem to work. Here is what my html looks like:

```html
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw margin-bottom" aria-hidden="true"></i> PROTOTYPE<font color="#37c6f5">MY</font>SKETCH<strong></strong></a> </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="about.html" class="dropdown-toggle">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
  </nav>
```

Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: show us the Javascript code that you tried..

Comment: Apologies. It was from another stackoverflow solution.

Comment: $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});

Comment: also what do you mean by it doesn't work? it seems correct though.. I assume it the `shrink` class you also change the `background-color`.

Comment: What do you mean by it's the shrink class? Should I be adding shrink into the div classes for my navbars

Comment: I mean "in the shrink class"..

Answer (score 1):

```
Using Jquery and Css you can change the background color of navbar with scrolling:

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) { 
      $('.navbar').addClass('shrink'); 
    } else { 
      $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink'); 
    } 
  }); 
 });

CSS for that:
.navbar{
   transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
   background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.navbar.shrink{ 
   background: #dddddd 
}

change color as per your requirement.
```